# Matplotlib boolean coloring

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I would like to graph a 3d plot of a sphere, which colors sections differently according to some function of the theta, phi coordinates.  I could graph two separate graphs, one of each color, but I'm not sure exactly how the gridding/meshing works when plotting.  Viz. I want to grid/mesh over all thetas/phis in a sphere, but then throw out certain pairs given a boolean function.  Is this possible?  Attached is a picture of a scatterplot that does what I'd like to do with surfaces.[image: colored sphere]

Comment: Do you have any code for the plotting of your sphere (without the colour change obviously)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [scatter3d_demo.py](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/mplot3d/scatter3d_demo.py) found in the [matplotlib tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

THETA, PHI = np.ogrid[0:2*np.pi:40j, 0:np.pi:30j]

X = 10 * np.cos(THETA) * np.sin(PHI)
Y = 10 * np.sin(THETA) * np.sin(PHI)
Z = 10 * np.ones_like(THETA) * np.cos(PHI)

def func(THETA, PHI):
    mask = (THETA < np.pi/2) & (np.pi/3 < PHI) & (PHI < 2 * np.pi/3)
    return np.where(mask, 1, 0.5)

C = func(THETA, PHI)

x = X.ravel()
y = Y.ravel()
z = Z.ravel()

c = C.ravel()
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=c, s=30, vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

---

Note you could also color patches on a sphere using `plot_surface`:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

THETA, PHI = np.ogrid[0:2*np.pi:40j, 0:np.pi:30j]

X = 10 * np.cos(THETA) * np.sin(PHI)
Y = 10 * np.sin(THETA) * np.sin(PHI)
Z = 10 * np.ones_like(THETA) * np.cos(PHI)

def func(THETA, PHI):
    mask = (THETA < np.pi/2) & (np.pi/3 < PHI) & (PHI < 2 * np.pi/3)
    return np.where(mask, 1, 0.5) 

C = func(THETA, PHI)
jet = plt.cm.jet
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=2, cstride=2, facecolors=jet(C))
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]